# Is it possible to disable service discovery with environment variables in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

As we know, kubernetes supports 2 primary modes of finding a Service - environment variables and DNS, could we disable the first way and only choose the DNS way?

Comment: I recommend using the DNS way. Not sure we have option to disable the environment variable.

Answer (score 16):

As shown in this [PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/68754), this feature will land with Kubernetes v1.13. From the PR (as Docs are not available yet) I expect it to be the field `enableServiceLinks` in the pod spec with true as default.

Edit: It has been a while and the PR finally landed. The `enableServiceLinks` was added as an optional Boolean to the [Kubernetes PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#podspec-v1-core).

For the record: [using DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#dns) to discover service endpoints is the recommended approach. The `docker link` behavior, from where the environment variables originate, has long been [deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/#link-environment-variables).

Answer (score 4):

Per kubernetes v1.8 [source](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.8.0/pkg/kubelet/kubelet_pods.go#L449), it's impossible to disable services discovery with environment variables.

Only service meet either condition is exposed by envVars.

- service in the same namespace as the pod;
- `kubernetes` service in the `default` namespace;

Even though, these environment variables can be overwritten by `env` and `envFrom` defined in pod template.

I'm wondering what's your scenario, maybe we can figure out some workaround.

Comment: Is it supported in 1.13?  I just think it's useless and do not want to see so many useless envs.